# I am getting an exception while working with JSON library to get data on an android application. It says JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONarray

Tags: android, json

This is my android (java) code, where I am trying to fetch data using json library (volley).

```
private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            String name = person.getString("id");
                            String email = person.getString("title");

                            jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                        }
                        txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hidepDialog();
            txtResponse.setText(error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

It works for one json source link, and does not for the other.

Working on json source : http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

Not working on json source :  http://cambuzz.co.in/public/Inside/app_all.php

Comment: on which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: Interesting, because neither of those should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON URL you provided returns a JSON object (which itself contains an JSON array)...  change your `JsonArrayRequest` to a `JsonObjectRequest`.

Comment: This is the right way! Another way is creating a general gson request that returns a JsonElement.